# How do variable declarations within types work in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

I'm trying to learn Fortran, and I've found that there aren't very many tutorials out there (probably due to it being an old language). The ones I have found are vague and undescriptive, and as I've gone into more complex things it has become harder and harder to guess what said tutorials are saying.
My current issue is with creating types. The tutorial contains examples such as:

```
module m_shapes
  implicit none
  private
  public t_square

  type :: t_square
  real :: side
  contains
    procedure :: area  ! procedure declaration
  end type

contains

  ! Procedure definition
  real function area(self) result(res)
    class(t_square), intent(in) :: self
    res = self%side**2
  end function

end module m_shapes
```

This compiles fine, so I know it works.

When I try to do something similar like this:

```
program type_test
    implicit none
    type :: thingy(a)
        real :: a
    end type
end program
```

It doesn't compile with errors like "The component at (1) that appears in the type parameter list at (2) has neither the KIND nor LEN attribute"

The tutorial I found does not explain types well enough, and I've tried things like `real,kind :: a = kind(0.0)`, but to no avail. Does anybody know what's wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. You had to search really badly because there are actually many tutorials for Fortran. Maybe you searched for "Fortran 90" (as the tag you used suggests) but that is actually very old, completely obsolete and mostly abandoned. But Fortran continues to develop and thebcommunity mostly uses modern revisions of the standard. You can start at  https://fortran-lang.org/

Comment: Please note that even your exampke is **not** Fortran 90 but at least Fortran 2003.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not explain, what you actually want to do. Or your words are not nearly clear enough. We can tell you why your attempt produces the error, but I have no idea what you actually want to do.

---

Perhaps you just wanted

```
program type_test
    implicit none
    type :: thingy
        real :: a
    end type
end program
```

without the `(a)`? That declares a simple type with one component. But hard to guess if this is what you wanted and what you tried with the `(a)`.

It does not declare any variable with that type. That is done using

```
  type(thingy) :: var
```

---

The syntax

```
  type :: thingy(a)
        real :: a
  end type
```

attempts to declare a [*parametrized derived type*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24372093/problems-with-parametrized-derived-types-in-fortran-2003). These types can depend on a kind or length parameter. These parameters must be integers. If it is a kind parameter, it allows to declare variables of the type with varying values of these parameters. Then the kind of some components of the type (you know what kind is, right? [Fortran 90 kind parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter) ) get their kind according to the value of the parameter. If it is a length parameter, it allows the length of some array or string components of the derived type to be parametrized - set during the variable declaration.

These parameters that appear in the parenthesis must be integer components and must have the `kind` or `len` attribute.

For example

```
  type :: param_type(k,l)
     integer, kind :: k
     integer, len :: l
     real(kind=k), dimension(l) :: array
  end type param_type

  type(param_type(kind(1.), 10)) :: o_sp_10  
  type(param_type(kind(1.d0), 20)) :: o_dp_20
```

The values of the parameters are set during the declaration of those `o_sp_10` and `o_dp_20` objects. I do not want to go into more details.